# BizTalk map testing error

Tags: xslt, biztalk, biztalk-mapper, biztalk-2016

I migrate one project from BizTalk 2010 to BizTalk 2016. I have one map with a functoid which calls an external dll file MyCompany.Common.Utilities.dll.

The XSL code is this:

```
<xsl:attribute name="discountedExtendedPrice">
    <xsl:variable name="rawDiscountedUnitAmt">
        <xsl:value-of select="b:BETRG" xmlns:b="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/INVOIC02/INVOIC02/700"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="processedDiscountedUnitAmt" 
    xmlns:myScriptPrefix="http://MyCompany.Common.Utilities" 
    select="myScriptPrefix:ProcessStringAsDecimal($rawDiscountedUnitAmt)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$processedDiscountedUnitAmt"/>
```

When I run, or test the map, I get the following error:

> XSL transform error: Unable to write output instance to the following 
>   `<file:///C:\Users\asdf\Desktop\Invoices.xml>`. 
>   Cannot find a script or an extension object associated with namespace 
>   'http://MyCompany.Common.Utilities'.*

The map runs in the old environment properly (BizTalk 2010). The problem appears only in BizTalk 2016

MyCompany.Common.Utilities.dll is deployed and registered in GAC

Comment: I'd suspect this is a 32bit vs. 64bit issue - you could create a simple console application referencing your DLL and see if it works when running in 64bit mode.

Comment: if I delete the XSL code and use the dll as external assembly, it works.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved

[Calling an external assembly from Custom XSLT in BizTalk Server 2010 Maps](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Calling-an-external-c74ce8dc)

I should have configured the field Custom Extension XML in Grid Properties